# xCode search bar crash when I'm trying to query data with parse

Tags: ios, objective-c, searchbar

So here's the code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
     _queriedResults = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init]
}

-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText{
    [_queriedResults addObjectsFromArray:[self searchBarQuery:[searchText lowercaseString]]];
}
-(NSArray*)searchBarQuery:(NSString*)searchedUser{
    NSArray * users;
    PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];
    [query whereKey:@"username" equalTo:[searchedUser lowercaseString]];
    users = [query findObjects];
    return users;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = [_queriedResults[indexPath.row]username];
    return cell;
}
```

So those are the main functions I'm using in my view controller class. I've done some debugging and queriedResults does succesfully get the name of the user I was searching, but then my tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath makes the app crash when queriedResults finally has values inside its array. I've set the cell identifier and the code is working fine when I test it with a normal temp array.. I don't know why it's crashing when I query it from the parse database.

This is the message I get when the app crashes.

NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier cell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'

I'm also getting this error -

Assertion failure in -[UISearchResultsTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:],

But I have the cell registered I thought.. which is why it works with other arrays when I'm testing. I don't know what's wrong with the code.

Comment: The `_queriedResults` is the only thing you change when testing? Are you using a search results controller?

Comment: surely it's not Xcode's search bar that crashes, is it?

Comment: I'm using search bar and search display controller, I'm also getting this error - Assertion failure in -[UISearchResultsTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:],

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are using a UISearchDisplayController or a UISearchController. In both cases, they tend to reuse the cellForRow method with a *new* table view that is maintained by the controller. One solution is to register for the cells on this new table view controller, another solution is to ask the original table view to dequeue the cell for the new table view.

For more information about the older UISearchDisplayController, see http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2012/09/06/search-bar-table-view-storyboard.html

For more information about the newer UISearchController, see http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2015/02/16/updating-to-the-ios-8-search-controller.html

Comment: I just need to figure out why my table view isn't correctly showing the array I get from querying from a database but crashing, but it's working fine when it's just a normal array.